# How to let worker role app to access files from web role instance

Tags: .net, azure, webrole

we have a windows service , and now need to change to worker role application, but this service need to get some file from web application every time, as i know, web role and worker role are running in different instance, so my question is: how to let worker role application to access the file from web role instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of either `blob storage` or `azure file service` for that purpose.

Since you're migrating an existing application, I would recommend going with azure file service. Basically what you will do is create a share and map that share as a network drive on both web role and worker role when the role starts. Web role will then write a file to this share using standard file API. To notify the worker role that a file is there to be processed, web role could write a message to a queue which is being polled by worker role. Upon receipt of the message, worker role will read the file and process that file.

You may find this blog post useful regarding azure file service: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx.

Comment: many thanks, two questions left: 1. My service execute task depends on the data in Database(get data from DB within certain time interval), so i think i can ignore the azure message queue, right?  2. I'm not going to move my files to blob storage since it's a part of web app and it's huge, i can not sync all files to azure file service every time after package deploy, so this may cause problem.

Comment: Regarding 1, you're right. You need some mechanism to let worker role know. Regarding 2, may I suggest you edit your question and put it there. Its an interesting problem. Just out of curiosity, how are these files in web role created and how big are they. If you can describe that as well, it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your response, it'a little complex about the second question, we are now using lucene.net to generate many huge size of index files, and i'm going to move index files to blob storage, but it's not good to download index files every time when customer use search function, this will take a lot of time and bad performance, so i cache the index files in local file system(under web app), we use service to re-generate index files, upload to blob, but also need to update the local index files as they are used as cache, this trouble me a lot.

Comment: by the way ,file service is in preview version and  i can not found it in azure storage management